# nagios.log format - field definition

Tags: logging, nagios

I've been looking all over for an hour or so.  I thought I had seen something here but I cannot find it.

I'm looking for the record definition for nagios.log. Specifically I'm trying to figure out what the number represents.  In this entry I want to understand what the "1" is.

[1549377065] SERVICE ALERT: esgg;HTTP;CRITICAL;SOFT;1;CRITICAL - Socket timeout

I thought for sure this would be easy to find but I was wrong or just lost in the woods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is related to [soft&hard](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/statetypes.html) mechanism in the Nagios.
For example, if your service `esgg` have `max_check_attempts 3` setup in your service definition then you will see something like this:

```
[1549377065] SERVICE ALERT: esgg;HTTP;CRITICAL;SOFT;1;CRITICAL - Socket timeout
[1549377195] SERVICE ALERT: esgg;HTTP;CRITICAL;SOFT;2;CRITICAL - Socket timeout
[1549377265] SERVICE ALERT: esgg;HTTP;CRITICAL;HARD;3;CRITICAL - Socket timeout
```

You need 3 bad continuous check to get HARD state and notification.

Comment: I know the first number between [ ] is the timestamp.  That isn't the number I'm referring to.  Its the 1 between SOFT and CRITICAL.  That's what I'm trying to figure out.  Thank you for responding.

Comment: Thanks!  I was sure somebody knew.  Appreciate the link too.

Answer (score 0):

In the Nagios service definition you have set the "check interval", "retry interval", and "max check attempts". In other words, nagios will check the service every `check interval` minutes and then if it is not OK, it will check again every `retry interval` minutes, for `max check attempts` times. The number you are referring to is how many times Nagios has checked the service since it went into a "non OK" state. It will increment until it reaches `max check attempts` or goes back to an OK state.

Comment: Your answer is the same as Rohlik.  Thank you for responding.